# how to write/read cache in javascript (visited page today)?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cordova

I have one HTML app made in phonegap.
The first welcome page has a button. Wenn I click it I am randomly navigated to one of my ten another pages(for example Page2.html). Now I'd like with the help of javascript save in the cache wich of the ten pages was randomly chosen and I was navigated to, and the next time the same day wenn I click the button on my start page i'd like to be navigated exactly to the one of this ten pages(Page2.html)

Thak you very much

Comment: Use localStorage and save the visited pages in a stringified array (and keep pushing to it)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some kind of database to achieve it. You could use `localStorage`, but as far as I know localStorage is currently treated as temporary by ios. That means it can wipe out localStorage data when it'll need memory. So you will need a database to save the viewed pages. You can use webSQL.